# "Large amount of calories" vs. "high amount of calories"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, collocation

Is it more typical to say that there are a *large amount* of calories or a *high amount* of calories?

For example:

> Chocolate cake contains a high/large amount of calories.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the most common phrasing I've personally seen is:

> It is *high in* calories.

The number of calories can be thought of as either a number (number of) or aggregate (amount of).   Other answers/comments have indicated that there's debate over which is more common/appropriate, but what one you use influences which adjective you pick.

Per [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=large%20number%20of,high%20number%20of,large%20amount%20of,high%20amount%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=):

> large number of --> **Most Common**
>
> large amount of --> **Common**
>
> high number of --> **Uncommon**
>
> high amount of --> **Almost Unheard Of**

Comment: Really Lynn, _"what one you use"_ - what were you thinking of?

Comment: @MikeM:  Huh?   (Apparently Huh? by itself is not a valid comment so I must say more than that even though really that's all I have to say.)

Comment: I'm not over-fond of any of your four alternatives. The calorie is fundamentally a unit (of energy), and one wouldn't often use _large number of / amount of (etc) joules_ or _hours_. Admittedly, _calories_ is used as a shorthand with foods for 'available energy' which would accept 'large amount', but I'd hedge with 'a lot of' which does not clash with either notion - mass usage (energy) or number of calories.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Oh, I agree - that's why I led off with my favored alternative.  Yours is good too.  I was just trying to answer the OP's direct question about large/high.

Comment: Sorry, Lynn. I wish people wouldn't ask for a decision involving _two_ questionable variants.

Answer (score 1):

Bill Franke's comment suggests that this question asks for “a proper distinction between count and non-count nouns”, then reasons that because uncountable substances take  “amount” *ie* “total number or quantity : aggregate” while countable substances take “number” the answer is like  “Chocolate cake contains a large number of calories”, calories being countable.  I suppose his comment is intended to rule out either of the alternatives mentioned in the question.

However, the question actually asks which of two forms is  *more typical*.  That question can be answered by reviewing corpuses of English text.   For example, the English 2009 [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=large+amount+of+calories%2Chigh+amount+of+calories%2Clarge+number+of+calories&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) corpus shows no usage¹ of *high amount of calories*, and shows that in recent decades, *large number of calories* appears at least twice as frequently as *large amount of calories*.  As another example, [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (Corpus of Contemporary American English) includes one instance of “large amount of calories” and no instances of the other two phrases.  (But as Barrie England notes in a comment, the shorter phrases  “amount of calories” and  “number of calories” appear 51 times and 137 times, respectively.)

¹ In google ngrams, phrases that appear in fewer than 40 books are not treated, *ie* show as zero.  (See [FAQ question](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info)  “Why are you showing a 0% flatline when I know the phrase in my query occurred in at least one book?”)

Comment: The COCA has 51 records for _amount of calories_ and 137 for _number of calories_. The BNC figures are 15 and 26.

Answer (score 0):

It is more typical to say that there are a *large* amount of calories than a *high* amount of calories.

Comment: Isn’t *amount* singular?

Comment: @tchrist. Yes, there's _one_ amount of many calories and that amount is large.

Answer (score 0):

Here the bone of contention is a question asked for the English Grammar part of the Kerala Public Service Commission Examination conducted on the 5th of January, 2013.

The question runs:

> Chocolate cake contains a ***_*_** amount of calorie.
>   The options given are: high; numerous; large; big

What the Public Service Commission expects is:

> Chocolate cake contains a large amount (high amount) of calorie.

But here the problem is: the very question is wrongly constructed.

Cake is a common noun and so the question should have been:

> Chocolate cake**s** contain....

Again, the noun calorie should have been in the plural.  So, the question should have been:

> Chocolate cakes contain ... calorie**s**.

The most accurate answer, of course, is:

> Chocolate cakes contain a large amount of calories.

The question can be challenged in a court of law, whatever be the answer given by the PUBLIC SERVICE COMMISSION.

Comment: You are quite right about the singular *calorie*; but *Chocolate cake* here is considered under the category of *edible substance* rather "edible item", so the singular in noun and verb is quite proper.